# Can colon (:) be used for assignment in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm new in JavaScript. I was programming and I saw some used

`const PI : 3.14`

I'm puzzled how ':' notion can be used to assign values to variables. Can anyone explain to me when ':' is used to assign values to variables? That'll be really helpful ^^

Comment: supposed to be `=` not `:`, where did you see that?

Comment: In some codes I saw people used colon to assign values to a particular variable. I've seen mostly within Objects. So, I was curious how it works? :  )

Comment: if it's in an object literal, it would be defined as `{ PI : 3.14 }` so there would be no `const`

Comment: So, If I use const/let/var methods I always need to use ```=``` method right?

Comment: to assign to a variable you use `=`, nothing else -- see [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types#declarations)

Comment: Generally you should include a [example] into the question, not just a snippet that doesn't even compile.

Comment: Sorry I was new so I did not add it. But, thanks for the input I'll add an example from now on in all the questions I ask on Stack :  )

Answer (score 0):

If you are just assigning a variable, you can't use a colon. What you want is `const PI = 3.14`. Colons can be used for other purposes however, for example, setting keys in an object:

```
const myObject = {
    key: "my new value"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

NO! That is the wrong syntax and will throw error in JS.

Either you write

```
const PI = 3.14;
```

OR

```
const Obj1 = {PI: 3.14}
```

These, are the valid syntax in JS.

Comment: Thanks it was really helpful! And solved my issue.